# Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Prove or Disprove that A disconnected implies that $\overline{A}$ is also disconnected.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, real-numbers

Having trouble on proving this, I was thinking of doing the contrapositive.
Suppose $\overline{A}$ is connected i.e. $(\forall B, C \subseteq \overline{A}) (B \cup C \neq \overline{A})$ or $(\overline{B} \cap C \neq \emptyset)$ or $(B \cap \overline{C} \neq \emptyset)$. I have written much more of what I tried on paper, but it seems pointless to put what I tried. I pretty much assumed to show that $A$ is connected, let $A = B_1 \cup C_1$ where $B_1$ and $C_1$ are both subsets for $B$ and $C$ from above.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "Your question should be clear without the title.
After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong. $\mathbb Q$ is disconnected but its closure is connected.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ is a very simple counterexample

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have already pointed out, this claim is wrong. But what is true is, that for a topological space $X$ and a connected subspace $A\subset X$, any subspace $B\subset X$ with $A\subseteq B\subseteq\overline{A}$ is connected. For a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569860/showing-that-a-superset-b-of-a-set-c-is-connected-if-b-subset-bar-c), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306663/let-x-d-be-a-metric-space-if-a-subset-x-is-connected-b-subset-x-with?rq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328980/proposed-proof-of-if-a-subset-b-subset-bara-and-a-is-connected-then?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

$A=(0, 1) \cup (1, 2) $ is disconnected subset of $\Bbb{R}$ with euclidean topology. But $\overline{A}=[0, 1]\cup[1, 2]=[0, 2]$ is connected.